# Can time theoretically be changed by altering physical characteristics?

Tags: philosophy-of-science, time

Is time a factor that can be altered by altering the physical properties that helped contribute to the concept of time?

Comment: Can you make clearer why you think this is question is a philosophy of science question rather than physics question? (as in edit the question to make it clearer)

Comment: I agree that this was a physics question, as my answer below makes clear.

Comment: As written it's a physical question, but one can draw out some philosophical considerations implicit in it.

Answer (score 2):

No. Time is a defined unit of measurement. The second is defined as the duration of 9 192 631 770 periods of the radiation corresponding to the transition between the two hyperfine levels of the ground state of the cesium 133 atom at 0 K. This is an intrinsic property of a single cesium atom. As per http://physics.nist.gov/cuu/Units/http://physics.nist.gov/cuu/Units/second.html:

> The unit of time, the second, was defined originally as the fraction
>   1/86 400 of the mean solar day. The exact definition of "mean solar
>   day" was left to astronomical theories. However, measurement showed
>   that irregularities in the rotation of the Earth could not be taken
>   into account by the theory and have the effect that this definition
>   does not allow the required accuracy to be achieved. In order to
>   define the unit of time more precisely, the 11th General Conference on
>   Weights and Measures (CGPM)) (1960) adopted a definition given by the
>   International Astronomical Union which was based on the tropical year.
>   Experimental work had, however, already shown that an atomic standard
>   of time-interval, based on a transition between two energy levels of
>   an atom or a molecule, could be realized and reproduced much more
>   precisely. Considering that a very precise definition of the unit of
>   time is indispensable for the International System, the 13th CGPM
>   (1967) decided to replace the definition of the second by the
>   following (affirmed by the International Committee on Weights and
>   Measures in 1997 that this definition refers to a cesium atom in its
>   ground state at a temperature of 0 K):
>
> **The second is the duration of 9 192 631 770 periods of the radiation
>   corresponding to the transition between the two hyperfine levels of
>   the ground state of the cesium 133 atom.**

If you were to measure the duration of 9 192 631 770 periods of the radiation corresponding to the transition between the two hyperfine levels of the ground state of the cesium 133 atom at 1 K (one degree above absolute zero as opposed to absolute zero), you would get a slightly different answer, but you wouldn't be measuring time as it is currently defined unless you corrected for the temperature difference.

The twin "paradox" in special relativity doesn't change this. The paradox presumes that both twins have clocks based on the same unit of time. That the twins are traveling in two different inertial reference frames, one at rest and one traveling at close to the speed of light, say, doesn't change the physical properties of either clock.

Answer (score 1):

Sure. The so-called "twin paradox" in special relativity trivially answers that question "yes". In fact, I believe they've flown atomic clocks on the ISS to experimentally demonstrate that kind of thing, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomic_Clock_Ensemble_in_Space (and google coughs up lots of similar links). Your phrase "altering the physical properties" might need to clarify "properties" to accommodate relativity's postulates more directly. "State of motion (inertial frame)" or "gravitational potential" (for general relativity tests) would be more direct examples, but I'm supposing you'd accept those as "physical properties".

Comment: See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_analysis_for_the_Global_Positioning_System sectiob Relazivity

Answer (score 0):

Quoting from

https://belate.wordpress.com/2011/02/17/aristotle-definition-of-time-in-physics/

> Aristotle defines time as “a number of change in respect of the before
>   and after” (“arithmos kineseos kata to proteron kai husteron,” 219b1). - Physics Book IV

However, with special relativity, the velocity of the observers means that the meaning of before and after is altered, and so the concept of time is altered (from Aristotle's definition).

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relativity_of_simultaneity#Explanation

> For example, a car crash in London and another in New York, which
>   appear to happen at the same time to an observer on the earth, will
>   appear to have occurred at slightly different times to an observer on
>   an airplane flying between London and New York. The question of
>   whether the events are simultaneous is relative: in the stationary
>   earth reference frame the two accidents may happen at the same time
>   but in other frames (in a different state of motion relative to the
>   events) the crash in London may occur first, and in still other frames
>   the New York crash may occur first.

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically, yes; though of course we can't know in fact, since these physical characteristics aren't something we can change; so also, theoretically, no.

David Lewis, the philosopher, in his book *Plural Worlds*, develops a cosmology where logical coherence is the only constraint; were we able to compare time across these worlds, then we might find worlds where the notion of time does differ - the duration of a second in this world differs in kind from a second in that world.

Smolin, the physicist, implicitly takes advantage of this framework where he develops a cosmology of evolving worlds where physical constants - that specify the basic features of the world, as say in the Standard Model - are driven towards the values of our own world.

There are also physical theories which allow for such variations close to the Big Bang in *this* world as an alternative to inflation.